# XeLaTeX compiling and ToC

Tags: texmaker

I needed to use Times New Roman font for my thesis and to do that I switched to compiling with XeLaTeX from PdfLaTeX.  I'm using MikTex with TexMaker, and with the Quick Build options I was using it was PdfLaTex + Bib(la)tex + PdfLatex (x2) + View Pdf.  But the only Quick Build option for XeLaTeX is XeLaTeX + View Pdf.  Does XeLaTeX compile multiple times to update the ToC, LoF, etc. and why don't I have to run Bib(la)tex separately?

Comment: The build cycle should be the same in terms of bibliographies, ToC, etc. If the Quick Build option for XeLaTeX does not have the bibliography nor the additional XeLaTeX runs you should be able to configure it to do so.

Comment: Some editors (e.g. TeXstudio which is somehow a fork from TeXmaker) support so called Magi Comment, like `% !TeX program = xelatex` to easily change the TeX engine without touching the build settings. Unfortunately TeXmaker doesn’t understand these and you must – I guess – change the build process yourself or use LaTeXMK or Arara. However it is totally easy possible to use (kind of) Times with PDFLaTeX, for example with `\usepackage{txfonts}`.

Comment: as far as toc is and bibliography are concerned xelatex and pdflatex are the same you will need the multiple runs in exactly the same manner using either xetex or pdftex